# How to route a single application's audio output as the microphone input in Windows 11?

Tags: audio, windows-11, microphone

Windows 11 has changed its System > Sound menu to not include options to access device-specific Advanced Sound options. I cannot find an option to change the source audio for Stereo Mix even when entering the device properties.

Is there a way to still route an applications audio to be the input in Windows 11 or would I need to revert to windows 10 for this feature?

Comment: Try:  Sound (system tray), right click on Settings (lower right) and that opens up main Settings.  Click on Sound.   Does that help

Comment: None of the options in sound redirect an applications audio output as the Stereo Mix or audio input

Comment: Maybe go to  Feedback Hub and submit your request

Answer (score 1):

There are third-party apps such as [Virtual Audio Cables](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/), [Synchronous Audio Router](https://github.com/eiz/SynchronousAudioRouter), and other [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/virtual-audio-cable/), that act as virtual patch-boards, sending output of an audio source to input of an audio sink. Some of these are free and open-source software.

One *caveat*: it may take a bit of learning to set up and configure some of these tools.